# Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-like

I'm trying to make a select in php with pdo.
It's working with a lot of req but not when I'm using a like, example :

**Query:**

```
SELECT * FROM projets WHERE `identifiantProjetRattachement` LIKE "%PC13287%" ORDER BY "identifiantProjetDSR"
```

This is my php code :

```
<?php
    function requette($requette,$table)
    {
        $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=spb', 'root', '');
        $sql =  "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='$table';";
        $req = $bdd->query($sql);

        $titres = array();

        while($resultat = $req->fetch())
        {
           array_push($titres,$resultat['COLUMN_NAME']);
        }

        // ON A LES TITRES DONC ON PASSE AU CONTENU
        $sql =  $requette;
        $req = $bdd->query($sql);

        $retour = "";
        $cpt = 0;
        $nbLigne = 0;

        while($resultat = $req->fetch())
        {
           $nbLigne++;
           $retour .= "<tr><td class='boutonTouteLaCase' onclick='surlignerLigneProjets(this);'></td><td>$nbLigne</td>";
           for($cpt=0;$cpt<count($titres);$cpt++)
           {
             if($titres[$cpt] != "id")
               $retour .= "<td>".utf8_encode($resultat[$titres[$cpt]])."</td>";
           }

           $retour .= "</tr>";
        }
        echo $retour;   
      }

    $requette = htmlentities($_POST['requette']);
    $table = htmlentities($_POST['table']);

    echo $requette."<br/>";
    echo $table."<br/>";

     echo requette($requette,$table);?>
```

Do you think it's an accent problem ? Or a problem due to a ' ?

PS : This req works on phpmyadmin.
Thanks for all.

Comment: The PHP error: `Call to a member function *****() on a non-object` I think usually occurs when the object is null. So check over your code for things that might return null (ie: if the record doesn't exist or something)

Comment: The `query` might be returning `false`.

Comment: Is it normal that phpmyadmin is returning me a line ?

Comment: You can try `LIKE '%' + $var + '%'`  but i don't see any LIKE in your php ?
else you must get punished to write 'requette'

Comment: like is in the $requette var :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are invalidating your own queries:

```
...

$requette = htmlentities($_POST['requette']);
$table = htmlentities($_POST['table']);

echo $requette."<br/>";
echo $table."<br/>";

echo requette($requette,$table);
```

Note that you are using `htmlentities($requette)` and later you try to run that exact query:

```
$sql =  $requette;
$req = $bdd->query($sql);
```

And that query will look like:

```
SELECT * FROM projets WHERE identifiantProjetRattachement
    LIKE &quot;%PC13287%&quot; ORDER BY &quot;identifiantProjetDSR&quot;
```

For the example that you mentioned. An invalid query.

So you should only use `htmlentities()` when you output your variable to the screen, but you should not change the variable itself:

```
// Don't do this:
// $requette = htmlentities($_POST['requette']);
// $table = htmlentities($_POST['table']);

// just do this:
echo htmlentities($requette)."<br/>";
echo htmlentities($table)."<br/>";

echo requette($requette,$table);
```

Apart from that I will assume that you only have access to this yourself as you are running user-provided sql queries directly so that would be very dangerous if an unauthorized user had access to that.

Comment: Thx for your help, know that i'm not alone to use this php page, but i did veriication before allow acces to this page. I don't understand what you said : "you are invalidating your own queries" can you explain please ?

Comment: @Antoine I just added an example. But look at your query, that is not valid sql.

Comment: Thank you so much, i removed the htmlentities and its ok :D Thanks thanks thnaks ^^

Answer (score 1):

In `where` condition use `column name` not `table name` `TABLE_NAME='$table';`

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='$table';
```

it would be

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME='$CONDITION';
```

Also `ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME is ASC OR DESC`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but look at the code please :D The first req is here to know the name of the columns in the table, so why do you make a req to know he columns name for every colums name ? And the order by is by "identifiantProjetDSR". My req works because phpmyadmin returns me a lihne when i give it to him.

Answer (score 1):

Check the doc of mysqli::query:
http://php.net/manual/de/pdo.query.php

It can return PDOStatement object (where fetch is possible) or FALSE on failure, so check, if there was an error in your sql query before trying to fetch any results.

```
$req = $bdd->query($sql);
if (!$req) {
  return false;
  // maybe give some better error message
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it don't change anything, just remove the error :P :'( (but realy thx for help :D)

Comment: Yeah sure, for that see the answer from @jeroen :)

Answer (score 0):

> Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in line what?

That point will tell you exactly where you are doing something wrong. Ensure you are not overwriting your query string by assigning it to a string and not an Object as specified by PDO.
Another is to ensure that your `$req->rowCount()` returns a value and not null before you call your `$req->fetch()`